# How to run slurm in the background?

Tags: slurm

To use allocated resources by slurm interactively and in the background, I use `salloc -n 12 -t 20:00:00&`. The problem is that this command does not redirect me to the compute node and if I run a program it uses resources of the login node. Could you please help me to find the right command?

```
 salloc -n 12 -t 20:00:00 a.out </dev/null&
```

but it fails :

```
salloc: error: _fork_command: Unable to find command "a.out"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to execute `salloc -n 12 -t 20:00:00&`. Then use ssh to connect to the allocated node (for example, `ssh node013`).

Comment: when I try to do as you suggest, it throws an error:
`salloc: error: Waiting for program to be placed in the foreground`

Answer (score 0):

Is `a.out` in your path? e.g. what does `which a.out` return?

Comment: it is not found, "/usr/bin/which: no a.out in (.......")